# How to store secrets in a CLI application in Go?

Tags: auth0, secrets

I am attempting to create a CLI application that is secured with Auth0 in Go. I need to include my Auth0 application's domain and client ID.

```
url := "https://{yourDomain}/oauth/device/code"

payload := strings.NewReader("client_id={yourClientId}&scope=%7Bopenid profile$7D")
```

Since this is a CLI application, I cannot use environment variables to store the secret values, as I do not want other users to know these values. How can I keep others from viewing these secrets after they have installed the CLI?

Comment: And in which way do other users have to know the environment? They'd only know the values in case you call your binary with `ENVVAR=foo yourbinary` - something that can be easily prevented. Providing secrets to CLI applications is the commonly accepted best practice.